# How to fit an auto ARIMA model in R over an irregularly spaced time series to forecast future values?

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, forecasting

We have the following data values and time series stamps:

```
Lines <- "date,time,data
 20/03/2014,07:10,9996792524
 21/04/2014,07:10,8479115468
 21/09/2014,07:10,11394750532
 16/10/2014,07:10,9594869828
 18/11/2014,07:10,10850291677
 08/12/2014,07:10,10475635302
 22/01/2015,07:10,10116010939
 26/02/2015,07:10,11206949341
 20/03/2015,07:10,11975140317
 09/04/2015,07:10,11526960332
 29/04/2015,07:10,9986194500
 16/09/2015,07:10,11501088256
 13/10/2015,07:10,11833183163
 10/11/2015,07:10,13246940910
 16/12/2015,07:10,13255698568
 27/01/2016,07:10,13775653990
 23/02/2016,07:10,13567323648
 22/03/2016,07:10,14607415705
 11/04/2016,07:10,13835444224
 04/04/2016,07:10,14118970743"
```

We have read these in R using the `zoo` library as follows:

```
z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, sep = ",", header = TRUE, 
              index = 1:2, tz = "", format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
plot(z)
```

Now we are trying to fit an auto ARIMA model on this time series data. However, we get the error:

```
amar_fit <- auto.arima(z)
#Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
#  0 (non-NA) cases
```

What are we doing wrong? And how do we successfully fit an ARIMA (or another) forecasting model over this irregularly space time series?

Comment: Data is fit into the `Lines` variable. I've updated my question to show where the data lies. Could you please tell me how to correct this error?

Comment: I'm expecting some predictions for the next 2-3 years, 2 predicted values each year -- doesn't matter what time or month or day it is. I just need to see how the trend is expected to rise each year